Approximate local minima for sum of inverse trigonometric functions
Let $\{a_1, a_2, ..., a_N\} \in [0, 1[^N$, I would like to approximate the minimum of the function
$$f(x) = x \sum_{i=1}^N \left(\sin(x)^2 - \sin(a_i x)^2 \right)^{-2} $$
in the domain $x \in {]0, \frac{\pi}{2}]}$, and express this approximation in function of $\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_N\}$.
I already considered using the derivative of the function : I find
$$\frac{\delta}{\delta x} f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{g(x) - g(a_i x)}{\left(\sin(x)^2 - \sin(a_i x)^2\right)^3}$$
where $$g(x) = \sqrt{1 + 16 x^2} \sin(x) \sin(x - \tan^{-1}(4x))$$
By graphically analysing the function $g(x)$, I was able to conclude that the value $x$ minimizing this function will be on the interval $[x_0, x_1]$, where $x_0 \approx 0.918299\ldots$ and $x_1 \approx 1.393249\ldots$
Is there a method which would allow me to provide a more precise answer or is this the best I can do without knowledge of the values $\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_N\}$ ?
